# Porque no se me visualizan una consulta JSON usando la libreria Volley (Web Services)?

Tags: android, mysql, json, webservice, android-fragment

Estoy intentando crear un web service usando la librería Volley, solo que al ejecutar mi app en un dispositivo físico no me aparecen los datos que estan alojados en un servidor gratuito.

Los datos ya estan en JSON pero no siguen sin visualizarse, ya en buscado en internet y no encuentro alguna solución.

FragmentEventos.java

```
public class FragmentEventos extends Fragment {

private static final String URL_EVENTS ="http://mece.260mb.net/models/eventos_json.php?i=1"; /*URL de los datos JSON*/
List<Eventos> eventosList = new ArrayList<>(); /*Lista para almacenar todos los eventos*/
RecyclerView recyclerView;





public FragmentEventos() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eventos, container, false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcv); /*Obtenemos la vista del RecyclerView desde XML*/
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    eventosList = new ArrayList<>(); /*Inicializar la lista de los Eventos*/

    //adapter = new EventosAdapter(getActivity(),eventosList);
    loadEvents(); /*Este método busca y analizas JSON para mostrarlo en el RecyclerView*/
    return view;
}
private void loadEvents(){     
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_EVENTS,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response); /*Convertir la cadena en objeto JSON de tipo array*/

                        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){ /*Atravesar el objeto*/

                            JSONObject event = array.getJSONObject(i); /*Obtener el objeto del Evento de JSON Array*/

                            eventosList.add(new Eventos( /*Agregando el evento  a la lista de Eventos*/
                                    event.getInt("id"),
                                    event.getString("tema"),
                                    event.getString("ponente"),
                                    event.getString("hora"),
                                    event.getString("fecha"),
                                    event.getString("lugar")
                            ));
                        }
                        EventosAdapter adapter = new EventosAdapter(getActivity(),eventosList); /*Crea el objeto adaptador y configura para el RecyclerView*/
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
    new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest); /*Agregar el stringRequest a la cola*/
}
```

}

EventoAdapter.java

```
public class EventosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventosAdapter.EventoViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Eventos> eventoList;



public EventosAdapter(Context context, List<Eventos> eventoList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.eventoList = eventoList;

}

@Override
public EventoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,null);
    return new EventoViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EventoViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Eventos eventos = eventoList.get(position);

    holder.tema.setText(eventos.getTema());
    holder.ponente.setText(eventos.getPonente());
    holder.lugar.setText(eventos.getLugar());
    holder.hora.setText(eventos.getHora());
    holder.fecha.setText(eventos.getFecha());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventoList.size();
}

class EventoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tema, ponente, lugar, fecha, hora;


    public EventoViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tema = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tema);
        ponente = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ponente);
        lugar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Lugar);
        fecha = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        hora = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hora);
    }
}
```

}

POJO.java

```
public class Eventos {
private int id;
private String tema;
private String ponente;
private String lugar;
private String hora;
private String fecha;



public Eventos(int id, String tema, String ponente, String lugar, String hora, String fecha) {
    this.id = id;
    this.tema = tema;
    this.ponente = ponente;
    this.lugar = lugar;
    this.hora = hora;
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTema() {
    return tema;
}

public String getPonente() {
    return ponente;
}

public String getLugar() {
    return lugar;
}

public String getHora() {
    return hora;
}

public String getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Estas conviertiendo la respuesta a JSONArray pero la [respuesta que da la url](http://mece.260mb.net/models/eventos_json.php?i=2) que muestras es un objeto, osea un `JSONObject`.

Cambia esto:

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try{
        // response es un JSONObject, no un array
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
```

Por:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try{
        // response es un JSONObject, no un array
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response);

        // obtienes el id del evento
        int eventId = data.getInt("id");
        //...
```

Ahora bien, por tu codigo se nota que esperas una lista de eventos así que tendrás que asegurarte de retornar un array en vez de un objeto para que te funcione sin hacer ningún cambio en tu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes analizar la respuesta:

```
{
id: "5",
tema: "Alsjsj",
ponente: "jjkajk",
hora: "1 am",
fecha: "2017-02-25",
lugar: "nnjj",
descripcion: "jnjknkj"
}
```

Hay algo importante a considerar,

La respuesta .Json puede ser de dos tipos:

> **- Si el .json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.**
>
> **- Si el .json inicia con `[` es considerado como Arreglo Json.**

Por lo tanto lo que recibes es un JSONObject:

```
  //JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response); 
  JSONObject event  = new JSONObject(response);
```

---

Realiza este cambio en tu código del método `loadEvents()`:

```
 private void loadEvents(){     
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_EVENTS,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        //JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response); /*Convertir la cadena en objeto JSON de tipo array*/

                        //for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){ /*Atravesar el objeto*/

                            JSONObject event =  new JSONObject(response);//array.getJSONObject(i); /*Obtener el objeto del Evento de JSON Array*/

                            eventosList.add(new Eventos( /*Agregando el evento  a la lista de Eventos*/
                                    event.getInt("id"),
                                    event.getString("tema"),
                                    event.getString("ponente"),
                                    event.getString("hora"),
                                    event.getString("fecha"),
                                    event.getString("lugar")
                            ));
                        //}
                        EventosAdapter adapter = new EventosAdapter(getActivity(),eventosList); /*Crea el objeto adaptador y configura para el RecyclerView*/
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
    new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest); /*Agregar el stringRequest a la cola*/
}
```

Comment: Pero son varias registros que quiero obtener, por eso use el for, solo que no entiendo porque al ejecutar el archivo eventos_json.php solo me trae un registro, si he registrado otros dos más y no aparecen

Comment: @SiulGutierrez entiendo lo que comentas, en realidad el error es generado porque no recibes un array de objetos json, estas recibiendo un json, debes modificar tu WS para recibir un array de eventos.

Comment: Ya quedo, ya funciona el WB. 

Creo que a veces se nos olvida leer un poco la documentación para encontrar posibles soluciones. Lo único que hice fue configurar la red y la caché.

Gracias